# line.width does not allow for multiple values when drawing a map

Tags: r, plotly

```
library(plotly)

xdf <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_us_cities.csv")

xdf$q <- with(xdf, cut(pop, quantile(pop)))

levels(xdf$q) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"), "Quantile")

xdf$q <- as.ordered(xdf$q)

list(
  scope = "usa", 
  projection = list(
    type = "albers usa"
  ), 
  showland = TRUE, 
  landcolor = toRGB("gray85"), 
  subunitwidth = 1, 
  countrywidth = 1, 
  subunitcolor = toRGB("white"), 
  countrycolor = toRGB("white")
) -> g

plot_geo(
  data = xdf, 
  locationmode = "USA-states", 
  sizes = c(1, 250)
) %>%
  add_markers(
    x = ~ lon, y = ~ lat, 
    size = ~ pop, color = ~ q,  
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ paste(xdf$name, "<br />", xdf$pop / 1e6, " million")
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = "2014 US city populations<br>(Click legend to toggle)", 
    geo = g
  ) -> p

p
```

Here is the error

```
Warning messages:1: `line.width` does not currently support multiple values. 2: `line.width` does not currently support multiple values. 3: `line.width` does not currently support multiple values. 4: `line.width` does not currently support multiple values.
```

How can i deal with the warning so as to display the map? The plot just shows the legend but the map is not visible.

Below is the session info

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252 
[3]LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                         
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252 

attached base packages:[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.0        pillar_1.3.0      compiler_3.5.1    later_0.7.5      
[5] plyr_1.8.4        bindr_0.1.1       tools_3.5.1       digest_0.6.18    
[9] jsonlite_1.5      tibble_1.4.2      gtable_0.2.0      viridisLite_0.3.0
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.2   rlang_0.3.0.1     shiny_1.2.0       rstudioapi_0.8   
[17] crosstalk_1.0.0   yaml_2.2.0        dplyr_0.7.8       httr_1.3.1       
[21] htmlwidgets_1.3   grid_3.5.1        tidyselect_0.2.5  glue_1.3.0       
[25] data.table_1.11.8 R6_2.3.0          plotly_4.8.0      ggplot2_3.1.0    
[29] purrr_0.2.5       tidyr_0.8.2       magrittr_1.5      scales_1.0.0     
[33] promises_1.0.1    htmltools_0.3.6   assertthat_0.2.0  xtable_1.8-3     
[37] mime_0.6          colorspace_1.3-2  httpuv_1.4.5      lazyeval_0.2.1   
[41] munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4
```

Am not sure what could be the problem if it works for others. I have included the sessionInfo as well as a follow up on a comment made earlier.

Comment: I do not get any error. Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()` into a separate code block? (this is also an exemplary example of how to post a question…wish more folks took the time you did to craft a q)

Comment: @hrbrmstr i have added session info

Comment: No, you did not paste the complete output of `sessionInfo()`. Please shrink your console width (long lines are a pain to read) and paste the _complete_ output.

Comment: I have added the complete sessionInfo

Comment: @hrbrmstr did you get a solution i could try?